# Is using a secure Back-end as a Service (BaaS) such as Parse.com an excuse to avoid an SSL website?

Tags: ssl, https, parse-platform

I was considering getting an SSL certificate and making my website use HTTPS. However, all the actual user information is sent across the Parse.com api, through HTTPS. So, even though users won't see a green address bar, their data is still secure.. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If literally all user data is handled by Parse, I would think so. However, part of the reason one might want to use HTTPS is that users will feel an added sense of credibility/legitimacy/security with your site with the green bar. (Short of inspecting network traffic, they have no way of knowing that the site is not sending some data in the clear to the main domain.)

Comment: Thanks! I agree, it does give a site more credibility. Although, using SSL doesn't seem to be enough; the green bar only comes when you fork out hundreds on an expensive certification authority. Or so I've heard.

Comment: I have used a free SSL certificate from startssl.com for more than a year now. It's not the full green bar but I do get the green padlock and it's enough for hosting FB tab apps, which was my main reason for needing one. (FB requires tab apps to serve content over HTTPS.)